# Javascript loop with alert

Tags: javascript, jsbin

Hi I'm confused with `alert` and `console.log`

```js
var count = [];

function iterate(number) {
  count.push(number);
  for (i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
    console.log(count[i]);
  }
}

iterate(2);
iterate(3);
iterate(4);
```

Console will give me 2,2,3,2,3,4 but when I change console.log(count[i]) to alert(count[i]); it will repeat just 2 three times, why?

```js
var count = [];

function iterate(number) {
  count.push(number);
  for (i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
    alert(count[i]);
  }
}

iterate(2);
iterate(3);
iterate(4);
```

It **doesn't** do that above, but it **does** [on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yuletoxome/edit?html,js).

Comment: Side note: It's not causing a problem in the above, but the code is falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. Declare `i` in `iterate`.

Comment: I'm confused, how? I thought alert inputs the elements of the count array, whenever I call the function, the length of the array will be increased

Comment: I mean when I try it in JS Bin(alert type), it will just alert 2 on the first ,2nd and 3rd call

Comment: I've updated my answer. You're running into JSBin's infinite loop protection, which is really aggressive when you're not running the output on its own because it's really easy to create infinitely loops while typing code (JSBin has the option of trying to run your code as soon as you pause typing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions show the same thing.

`count` starts empty.

On the first call, you push `2` into `count` so it has `[2]`, and then loop just once (`i == 0`), outputting `count[0]` (which is 2).

On the second call, you push `3` into `count` so it has `[2, 3]` in it, and loop twice (`i == 0`, `i == 1`), showing `count[0]` (2) and `count[1]` (3).

On the third call, you push `4` into `count` so it has `[2, 3, 4]` in it, and loop three times (`i == 0`, `i == 1`, `i == 2`), showing `count[0]` (2), `count[1]` (3), and `count[2]` (4).

---

Re your comment:

> I mean when I try it in JS Bin(alert type), it will just alert 2 on the first ,2nd and 3rd call

Ah! You're running into JSBin's "infinite loop protection." If you run it [here](http://jsbin.com/yuletoxome/edit?html,js) and look in the web console, you'll see

> Exiting potential infinite loop at line 5. To disable loop protection: add "// noprotect" to your code

...but if you run [the output page of that](http://output.jsbin.com/yuletoxome), it shows the full result.

The `alert` version triggers the infinite loop protection in the dev mode because it sees the same code happen more than once but more than 100ms apart (because of the delay while you dismiss the `alert`).